# Match two columns of similar data and place in two columns but in the same row

Tags: excel, vba, alignment

I have two columns of data:

- `Column A` has multiple cells in bold font that represent headers for paragraphs in English, and
- `Column B` has the same bolded headers as `Column A`, but in a different language.

**PROBLEM:**

The bolded cells in `Column A` and their equivalents in `Column B` don't show up in the same row. What I want is to align/match the two knowing that their equivalent may  show up a row before or a row after a given cell.

Here is an example of my data (`Column A` and `Column B` are the original data, and `Column E` and `Column F` are what I'm after):
[image]

This is my code:

```
Sub AlignTwoColumns()
'*same number of headers in each column is a must

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim C1PI As Integer 'column 1 position indicator = C1PI
                    'C1PI is used to locate the position of found bold cell in column 1 
Dim C2PI As Integer 'column 2 position indicator = C2PI
                    'C1PI is used to locate the position of found bold cell in column 2 
Dim C2SSI As Integer 'column 2 search starting indicator 
                     'once we find a bold cell in column 2 or 1 we 
                     'start our next search one from the next position of 
                     'the current found position thus we use C2ssI 
Dim C1SSI As Integer

Dim LastRow1 As Integer 'the last cell in coulmn 1
Dim LastRow2 As Integer 'the last cell in coulmn 2

With ActiveSheet
LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

C1SSI = 1
C2SSI = 1
C1PI = 1
C2PI = 1

For i = C1SSI To LastRow1
    If Range("A" & i).Font.Bold Then
    C1PI = i
        For j = C2SSI To LastRow2
            If Range("B" & j).Font.Bold Then
            C2PI = j
                If C1PI > C2PI Then
                     'cut cells in column 2 from C2PI to LastRow2
                     'paste cut cells in column 2 at position C1PI
                      Range("B" & C2PI & ":" & "B" & LastRow2).Select
                      Selection.Cut
                      Range("B" & C1PI).Select
                      ActiveSheet.Paste
                      'update the indicators 
                      C1SSI = C1PI + 1
                      C2SSI = C1PI + 1

                      With ActiveSheet 'update last cell position after copy and paste
                            LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                      End With

                      i = C1SSI
                      j = C2SSI

                      Exit For
                ElseIf C1PI < C2PI Then
                     'cut cells in column 1 from C1PI to LastRow1
                     'paste cut cells in column 1 at position C2PI
                      Range("A" & C1PI & ":" & "A" & LastRow1).Select
                      Selection.Cut
                      Range("A" & C2PI).Select
                      ActiveSheet.Paste

                      C2SSI = C2PI + 1
                      C1SSI = C2PI + 1

                      With ActiveSheet 'update last cell position after copy and paste
                            LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                      End With

                      j = C2SSI
                      i = C1SSI

                      Exit For
                Else
                    'do nothing
                     With ActiveSheet 'update last cell position after copy and paste
                            LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                     End With

                End If

            End If
        Next j
    End If
'the last i is not updating???!

Next i
End Sub
```

---

The code runs well to some value, but then exits before the final `i` value is updated.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the value of `i` does not exceed the original value of LastRow1? If yes perhaps a `do until i> .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` loop might work better

Comment: I thought of using "do until" , but why is the current code not working properly

Comment: Because ‘For i = C1SSI To LastRow1‘ keeps the first value of ‘LastRow1’ even if it gets updated inside the loop. If you need to update the loop iterator ending value during the loop then you need the construct ‘Do Until ... Loop’ and the likes

Comment: `For...Next` is usually for a predetermined number of loops. `Do Until` / `Do While` is for times, as in this case, when the number of loops is undetermined and may change with each iteration. Someone else with more formal training can probably explain this better than me.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad in this example it works, yet u used some actual data and it didn't work as intended. Maybe it's something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the final code that worked

```
Sub AlignTwoColumns2()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim C1PI As Integer 'column 1 position indicator = C1PI
Dim C2PI As Integer 'column 2 position indicator = C2PI
Dim C2SSI As Integer 'column 2 search starting indicator = C2SI
Dim C1SSI As Integer
Dim LastRow1 As Integer 'last cell in column 1
Dim LastRow2 As Integer 'last cell in column 2

With ActiveSheet
LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

C1SSI = 1
C2SSI = 1
C1PI = 1
C2PI = 1

i = 1
Do Until i > LastRow1
    If Range("A" & i).Font.Bold Then
    C1PI = i
        For j = C2SSI To LastRow2
            If Range("B" & j).Font.Bold Then
            C2PI = j
                If C1PI > C2PI Then
                     'cut cells in column 2 from C2PI to LastRow2
                     'paste cut cells in column 2 at position C1PI
                      Range("B" & C2PI & ":" & "B" & LastRow2).Select
                      Selection.Cut
                      Range("B" & C1PI).Select
                      ActiveSheet.Paste

                      C2SSI = C1PI + 1
                      j = C2SSI

                      With ActiveSheet 'update last cell position after copy and paste
                            LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                      End With

                      Exit For
                ElseIf C1PI < C2PI Then
                     'cut cells in column 1 from C1PI to LastRow1
                     'paste cut cells in column 1 at position C2PI
                      Range("A" & C1PI & ":" & "A" & LastRow1).Select
                      Selection.Cut
                      Range("A" & C2PI).Select
                      ActiveSheet.Paste

                  C2SSI = C2PI + 1
                  i = C2SSI
                  j = C2SSI

                  With ActiveSheet 'update last cell position after copy and paste
                        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                  End With

                  Exit For
            Else
                'do nothing if they are equal (aligned)
                C1PI = i
                C2PI = j
                C2SSI = C2PI + 1
                j = C2SSI
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
End If
i = i + 1 'increase the outer loop index
Loop
End Sub
```